# How can I make a data array from a table with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a form.

```html
<form id="form_step" action="form_stepb.php" method="post">
```

I have a table. Let's say it looks like this:

```html
<table class="data_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Header One:</th>
        <th>Header Two:</th>
        <th>Header Three:</th>
        <th>Header Four:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data_subrow">
        <td>
            <select class="subrow_type">
                <option value="choice_a">Choice A</option>
                <option value="choice_b">Choice B</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" class="phone" value=""> </td>
        <td><input type="text" class="phone_two" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="email" value=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Let's say the table has the ability to add a cloned row to the bottom of the table. So you could have 2,3,4 rows and so on when submitted.

Before I submit the form, I want to go through each row, gather the data, and make an array that gets turned into JSON, so the database holds the JSON for the data table in it.

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
$('#form_step').submit(function() {
    $('.data_table > tr.data_subrow').each(function() {
             
    });
});
```

I've been reading, searching, etc. But I need to know how I would take the values from each row (selected on the dropdown, text from the inputs) and make each row part of the array/object.

Can someone give me some direction on this?

Comment: [`$('#form_step').serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)?

Comment: Well, I gave that a try, and it was a handy way to gather all the variables, but the dynamic table in the form was not included in the gathering of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could you serializeArray() api attached to 'on' click event.

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(){
   var a = $("form").serializeArray();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, on a positive note, I figured it out. You have to target the form on a higher level if you have dynamic elements.

```
$(document).on("submit", "#form_step", function() {

});
```

Doing this allows you to target anything that was in the entire form, including dynamic elements. I feel like a bonehead for forgetting that.